# Convert value to unique value (ex John to John_1)

Tags: postgresql

The user writes his name and i want to store it into the database. If the name is already in the database i want to insert a postfix. ie Convert 'John' to the first one available between ('John_1', 'John_2' ... etc).

This is my way of doing this so far, but i'm sure there's a better way.

```
select n from
(
select 'John' n ,0 v
union
select 'John'||'_'||generate_series(1,100),generate_series(1,100)
) possible_names
where n not in
(select my_name from all_names u)
order by v
limit 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to worry about concurrency, the simplest way to guarantee uniqueness is by issuing insert statements until one succeeds. (This assumes you've a unique constraint, of course.)

Pseudocode:

```
while true
  if db.execute(insert_sql, [..., name + postfix, ...])
    break
  end
  counter += 1
  postfix = '_' + counter
end
```

You can make the procedure run in a shorter amount of time by starting at the maximum existing postfix (see the other answers with approaches to do that).

An awkward alternative would be to find the maximum existing postfix using a select statement, and then to try to acquire an [advisory lock](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) on something unique to the applicable name and postfix, e.g. `'username:' + name + postfix`. It's much less robust though, because it opens up the possibility of two transactions finding the same max_postfix, and then one transaction trying to acquire the lock immediately after other is done committing its insert and releasing that lock -- thus resulting in a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_username_proposal(text) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_names WHERE my_name = $1)=0 THEN
      $1
    ELSE
      $1 || '_' || COALESCE(MAX(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(my_name FROM '_[0-9]+$'), '_')::int), 0)+1
    END
  FROM
    all_names
  WHERE
    my_name ~ ($1 || '_[0-9]+$');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN num IS NULL THEN 'John' ELSE 'John' || '_' || num END AS new_name
FROM (
    SELECT max(substr(my_name, position('_' in my_name) + 1)::int) + 1 AS num
    FROM all_names
    WHERE my_name ilike 'John' || '_%'
) new_number
```

With all three instances of 'John' being where you pass in the name entered. (This is assuming that the user can't make an underscore part of their name and a number will always follow the underscore.)

Edit: This is also assuming that 'John' and 'john' should be treated the same. If they shouldn't, then replace the ilike with like instead.